# How do -1,0,1 aid the sort function when used implicitely in a subroutine?

Tags: arrays, perl, sorting, subroutine

I'm having some trouble with subroutines, namely the [sort](http://p3rl.org/sort) function being used to sort an array of numbers. I know if you use the sort function solely, it sorts using ASCII format, as the book describes this and that sorts in not the desired order. I'm aware and have an understanding of what gets returned by using `<=>` to compare values, even being introdued to `cmp` for strings (although I have not used it yet).

What I don't understand specifically is how it sorts them numerically - that actual process. I understand what is returned, but the book just says it returns -1, 0 and 1 and not how specifically the numbers end up finally sorted to `1 8 24 72 144 288`.

My example:

```
sub sort_by_number {
    return $a <=> $b;
}

@myArray = (1,24,8,144,72,288);

foreach(sort sort_by_number(@myArray)) {
    print("$_ ");
}
```

The example I understand fully. It makes perfect sense but I think that's mainly due to the coding:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

print("Please enter your name: ");
$name = <STDIN>;
chomp($name);
print("Please enter your age: ");
$age = <STDIN>;
chomp($age);

print(greeting($name, $age));

sub greeting {
    $msg = "Hello $_[0], ";
    determine_age($_[1],$msg);
}

sub determine_age {
    $num = ($_[0] <=> 18);
    if ($num == -1) {
        return "$_[1]you are under 18.($_[0])\n";
    } elsif ($num == 0) {
        return "$_[1]you will be a 19 on your next birthday!\n";
    } else {
        return "$_[1]you are over 18!($_[0])\n";
    }
}
```

Massively appreciative if someone could clarify.

Comment: If you have used the default sort, then you *have* used cmp, as that is the default.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your second example doesn't do any sorting.

To answer "*how it sorts them numerically - that actual process?*", [Perl internally implements sort using Merge Sort](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html) algorithm (was quicksort before Perl 5.6).

The algorithm itself is fairly complicated ([See Wiki for details)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort), BUT underneath it ends up comparing 2 numbers and deciding if one is bigger than the other, and performing some action depending on that decision. If you're curious about details, the algorithm part that needs the comparison is the `if first(left) ≤ first(right)` line on the Wiki example.

This is where the custom sort subroutine comes in - it answer "which number is bigger" question for the sorting algorithm (or, to be more specific, whether one number is less than or equal than another).

The way this is implemented, Perl's `sort` will internally call the "comparator" function, and pass it 2 arguments (by aliases `$a` and `$b`); and expect the function to return negative, zero or positive if the first is less than, equal or greater than the second one.

Comment: Firstly and it's no excuse, my materials generally are very poorly worded for newbies (provider has a reputation for this) and I'm very grateful for all replies!. Many thanks. I understood it as you describe and I just think, I overthought how it worked intricately instead of just accepting it does this as the book says. At this point, I think the mechanics of the algorithm will be in too much depth for me but I'll have a look. Many thanks!.

Comment: The function passed to `sort` can return any negative, zero, or positive value, not just `-1`, `0`, or `1`. So to do a numerical sort you could say `sort {$a-$b} @numbers_to_sort`. (Not that you *should* say that, necessarily)

Answer (score 4):

`<=>` is a numerical operator. When you compare `$a <=> $b`, it will return -1, 0, or 1 depending on whether the left argument is numerically less than, equal to, or greater than the right argument.

The `sort` function compares elements of a list by pairs, so it needs a comparison function who takes two arguments (a binary operator). `Sort` keeps comparing pairs and reordeing them until every item is "bigger" than following item in the list.

Comment: It took a little time but I think I have grasped that idea. Many thanks again all for your time and efforts!.